# Prove the identity between vectors A, B, C

Tags: vectors, products

2(A.B)(A.C)=(A.A)(B.C)+A^2.BC

A^2 is neither a dot or cross product

[it's used in optics, to calculate the aberrations of a non-axially symmetric system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQB4C.png)

Comment: This is not clear.  What does $A^2$ mean for a vector $A$?  What does $BC$ mean for vectors $B,C$?

Comment: not sure to be honest, this is the question I was given

Comment: Are you certain you copied the problem correctly with all symbols exactly as they appear?  In what context did this problem appear?  What similar things were you learning about at the time?  As it currently stands, the problem does not make sense and does not match standard usage of symbols for the supposed context.

Comment: I just a dded a snapshot... it's used in optics, to calculate the aberrations of a non-axially symmetric system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *appears* to me from the context like perhaps these $A,B,C$ are two dimensional vector representations of complex numbers and that the dot product is the usual dot product while the other product occurring is the usual product of complex or real numbers...  That is to say, if we have two vectors $[u,v]$ and $[x,y]$ we have $[u,v]\cdot [x,y]=ux+vy$ and we have $[u,v][x,y]=[ux-vy,uy+vx]$

Indeed, if we have $A=[a_r,a_i],B=[b_r,b_i],C=[c_r,c_i]$ on the LHS we would have:

$2(A\cdot B)(A\cdot C) = 2(a_rb_r+a_ib_i)(a_rc_r+a_ic_i) = 2a_r^2b_rc_r+2a_ra_ib_rc_i+2a_ra_ib_ic_r+2a_i^2b_ic_i$

On the RHS we have:

$(A\cdot A)(B\cdot C) + A^2\cdot BC$
$ = (a_r^2+a_i^2)(b_rc_r+b_ic_i) + [a_r^2-a_i^2,2a_ra_i]\cdot [b_rc_r-b_ic_i,b_rc_i+b_ic_r]$

$=(a_r^2+a_i^2)(b_rc_r+b_ic_i)+(a_r^2-a_i^2)(b_rc_r-b_ic_i) + (2a_ra_i)(b_rc_i+b_ic_r)$

Noting some nice cancellations, this simplifies as:

$2a_r^2b_rc_r+2a_i^2b_ic_i+2a_ra_ib_rc_i+2a_ra_ib_ic_r$ same as before.

Comment: You are very intelligent, thank you so much